# How to maintain the glassfish authentication state coming from an external site

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, glassfish

I'm going crazy creating a payment application. The problem of the moment is that. I set the glassfish authentication using jdbcRealms on the /secure/ directory. The user authenticate himself and enter in my application. When the user wants to pay, the application redirect him to the bank platform. After the payment the bank platform redirect the user again to my application sending some data.

The problem is that the bank platform wants to redirect the user in a page outside the /secure/ directory. It doesn't want a page under authentication. So I had to create a JSP page to grab data in an insecure directory. From the JSP I pass data to a Bean to write them in a db. But everyone can call the page and trying to passing it data. It's very dangerous. Is there a way to avoid that? Can I maintain the authentication state after the redirection?

Comment: @BalusC  that has no sense. I can receive only a predefined (by the bank) data. If I put the JSP page under /secure/ I don't receive data from bank platform.

Comment: @BalusC like you can see in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101709/jsp-page-set-bean-variables-but-give-nullpointerexception-when-bean-try-to-merge I can receive only predetermined parameters from remote host, but I can create new one in the middle. PS: I loose your answer in the post I linked.